# How can i implement payumoney integration in android?

Tags: android

How can I implement payumoney integration in Android? Success and failure url is must for that? How to redirect to the application after successful transaction?

Comment: https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html

Comment: Thank you @ SaravInfern .How can i integrate below link sdk to my application  https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App

Comment: Any procedure for get merchant key and salt value for payu money mobile integration @ SaravInfern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App

Using above link implemented successfully. thanks to all who are response.

Answer (score 0):

PayUmoney payment gateway integration in android app is very simple. first create a merchat account on payumoney.com https://www.payumoney.com/merchant-dashboard/

**Step By Step process**

**Step 1** get merchant key and salt key from payUmoney dashboard

**Step 2** upload server side PHP files for checksum HASH key

**Step 3** add dependency in android gradle file

**Step 4** get checksum hash using retrofit

**Step 5** start payumoney payment transactions

You can [download the PHP server files and android code from this reference link](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration/)

Answer (score 0):

PayUmoney payment gateway integration in android app is very simple. first create a merchat account on payumoney.com https://www.payumoney.com/merchant-dashboard/

Step By Step process

Step 1 get merchant key and salt key from payUmoney dashboard

Step 2 upload server side PHP files for checksum HASH key

Step 3 add dependency in android gradle file

please check below video for more details
https://youtu.be/exO1DdGnRhU
https://youtu.be/0_o-5iOq6iA